# Java Regex Range for ASCII

Tags: java, regex, cryptography

**Reworded question as it seems I wasn't specific enough;**

**Given a RSA system with *p* = 263, *q* = 587, public key *e* = 683 and private key *d* = 81599. Therefore *n* = *pq* = 154381. For a message, say "I AM A STUDENT", the encryption is conducted as follows:**

- **Convert any letter (including blank space) into a 3-digit ASCII code, i.e. 073 032 065 077 032 065 032 083 084 085 068 069 078 084.**
- **Join every two adjacent ASCII codes to form a block, i.e. 073032 065077 032065 032083 084085 068069 078084. (use 000 if last letter has nothing to join with).**
- **Using the encryption algorithm *c* = *m<sup>e</sup>* mod *n* to encrypt every block; *c<sub>1</sub>* = 73032<sup>683</sup> mod 154381 = 103300, etc.**

**Assume you are the receiver of a message: 33815872282353670979238213794429016637939017111351. What is the content?**

After a bit more consideration, I'm thinking that since I have to decode in parts, i.e. decode 33815 then 87228, etc., etc. That I should just split the decoded part in half, and check if each half is in the ascii range, if not, go back to the original and split it differently. Does this sound like a better solution than trying to hack something out with regex?

P.S. The decoding is considered homework, I have done this by hand and know that the message decodes to "i hate cryptography" (it seems my lecturer has a sense of humor), so you're not helping me do my homework. Turning this into a program is just something extra curricular that I thought might be fun/interesting.

Comment: Could you describe a little bit more what you are trying to achieve with RSA? We can help you with your regexp but I feel that there is something more wrong on top of all this. Fixing that error will likely remove the need for your complex solution described above

Comment: I have never used RSA directly on my own, but I can't imagine that this is the correct path to get your characters back.

Comment: Doesn't RSA decode a message into a `byte[]`?  I know of no cases that it decodes to a alphanumeric `String` representation.  You should be able to do a `new String(bytes)` to get the associated `String` back.

Comment: Do not just concat numbers into string. You'll have no way to get, where one number ends and another one starts.

Comment: Well, simplified RSA, for the sake of learning, is to convert each char of the message into it's 3 digit ASCII equivalent and then encode.
Encoding/decoding is based on a magic number (multiplication of the two public key prime numbers) and you must encode the message in parts that are smaller than the magic number (In this instance the magic number is 154381).

Comment: @kirilloid - see above explanation, encoded chars are not kept serparate, they are passed as one long string/number once encoded.

Comment: @FizzBuzz you need just to match 3 digits from string? Then it could be solved w/o regexs

Comment: Sometimes it may be 2 digits though, please see the original question.

Comment: You original question is vague. Question is hardly related to RSA. You need an algorithm to pack char codes into large numbers that way, you'll be able to do inverse operation. If you may write space as 32 and as 032 arbitrary, hardly you'll be able to reverse the process.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally an incredibly bad idea to have variable length records without a delimeter or index. In this case, the best approach is having a fixed width integer, with leading zeros.

That said, you do actually have an implicit delimiter, assuming you're always reading from start to end of the string without skipping at all. If you take 0 or 1 to indicate that it is a 3 digit number, and 2-9 to indicate a 2 digit number. Something like this would work:

`[01][0-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9]`

But really - just print your numbers into the string with leading zeros. Or look into 2 character hexadecimal encoding if you're worried about space. Or Base 64, or one of the other printable encodings.